# Listbox.items.count is always 0?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox

I am trying to determine if a list box has any text in it. I tried using a custom validator and the code below always has a result of 0 or false either when there is text or no text in the list box? How can I properly determine if there is text in a list box?

```
 Protected Sub CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles CustomValidator1.ServerValidate
        args.IsValid = Listbox.Items.Count > 0
    End Sub

Private Sub PopulateListBox()


        If NameTextBox.Text = "" Then

        Else
            ' Get value from text box
            Dim textBoxValue As String = Me.NameTextBox.Text

            ' Create new item to add to list box
            Dim newItem As New ListItem(textBoxValue)

            ' Add item to list box and set selected index
            Listbox.Items.Add(newItem)
            Listbox.SelectedIndex = Listbox.Items.Count - 1



            End If

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If IsPostBack Then
        ' Put call here to populate the listbox results from autocomplete extender selection
        PopulateListBox()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: When are you adding items to the listbox? When is this sub being called? It could be that a postback is rebinding the data in the listbox at some point.

Comment: I added the other code above that populates it. It is an autocomplete asmx text box and once the user selects a name it populates the list box

Comment: Are you clearing the listbox items on load? Can you show the page load  method (or any lifecycle events prior to that).

Comment: Sure, I added the page load

Comment: Is `NameTextBox` being cleared at any point? On postback you are checking the text box for a value and then displaying items in the listbox, if the listbox is empty after postback - one of these items has to be clearing or rebinding.

Comment: I am not clearing it anywhere, pretty much all the code I am using is above.

Answer (score 1):

By chance, is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If IsPostBack Then
        ' Put call here to populate the listbox results from autocomplete extender selection
        PopulateListBox()
    End If
End Sub
```

Is the IF statement supposed to be instead:

```
    If Not IsPostBack Then
```

You currently have it not binding the first time, but everytime after.

Comment: Thanks, I made that change but I am still getting a count of 0 when I have 2 lines of text in the list box.

Comment: Did you say AutoCompleteExtender?  When you select an item in the textbox from the AutoCompleteExtender, what do you do with the value?  Is there a button that then posts back to the server, or do you use javascript to do something?

Comment: Yes, I have an AutoCompleteExtender and a user will start typing a name and then select the appropriate one. Once it is selected I populate my listbox with the ID of the name they selected. As above it uses Listbox.Items.Add(newItem) Listbox.SelectedIndex = Listbox.Items.Count - 1

Comment: OK but by its nature I don't believe the AutoCompleteExtender posts back on selection.  Therefore I don't know the posted data has loaded in the textbox during page load.  Try your original code, minus my original change, in PreRender, and see if it works better there.